# Elasticsearch GET the last document for a given field if it exists

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I have a short question which seems to be simple, but I wasn't able to find any answer so far.

I want to retrieve on an Elasticsearch node, the last document given to a date field. But I want to have the last document, only for documents which contains a specific field.

For instance, let's say I want to get the last purchase which contains the field "**promotionCode**" :

Query :

```
http://elasticsearch:9200/store1/purchase/_search?q=vendor:Marie&size=1&sort=date:desc
```

where **store1** is my index, **purchase** a document type.

Now let's say I have these two documents in my ElasticSearch :

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "store1",
        "_type": "purchase",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "date": "2016-03-16T12:53:16.000Z",
            "vendor": "Marie",
            "promotionCode": "XYZ123"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "store1",
        "_type": "purchase",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "date": "2016-03-18T12:53:16.000Z",
            "vendor": "Marie"
        }
      }
]
```

The above query will retrieve the document of id 2, but I will not have any field "**promotionCode**" in my result.

If I want to get the last document, containing a specific field, how do I do ?

I explored "fields" filter, but it only send back void document if the field is not contained, and I read about Source filtering but not sure it is doing what I want ...

Thanks a lot for any hint !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo can try with this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": { "vendor": "Marie" }
    },
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": { "missing": { "field": "promotionCode" } }
        }
    },
    "sort": { "date" : "desc" },
    "size": 1
}
```

Comment: I tried this query :
`http://elasticsearch:9200/store1/purchase/_search?q=vendor:Marie&size=100&pretty=true&sort=sendDate:desc&filter={"bool":{"must_not":{"missing":{"field":"promotionCode"}}}`

But it returned me the 100 most recents documents, even if it doesn't contains the 'promotionCode'. Am I doing it right ?

Comment: You need put the JSON on a body to a POST request. If you need view results in browser you can use "postman" extension for chrome.

Comment: Oh ok that's what I thought, it's a POST request ... I already have Postman (yup its a great REST client !) but I thought I could achieve it with the GET verb.

Comment: Search by URI in elasticsearch only have some parameters. You can check the docu in this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

```
GET /store1/purchase/_search?q=vendor:Marie&size=1&sort=date:desc
{

       "query": {
    "exists" : {
        "field" : "promotionCode"
      }
   }

}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I tried this query :

`http://elasticsearch:9200/store1/purchase/_search?q=vendor:Marie&size=100&pretty=true&sort=sendDate:desc&exists=promotionCode`

and it does return all 100 most recent documents regardless of the presence of the field promotionCode too.

`exists={"field":"promotionCode"}` this doesnt work as well in the query .. Maybe I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Even in POST I couldn't make work this one ... I have ES 2.2

Comment: What query are you running? Please specify the exact query.

Comment: I tried to run POST http://elasticsearch:9200/store1/purchase/_search and with this body 
`{
       "query": {
    "exists" : {
        "field" : "promotionCode"
      }
   }
}`
I also tried GET http://elasticsearch:9200/store1/purchase/_search?q=vendor:Marie&size=100&sort=date:desc&exists=promotionCode